# Graphics glitches and artifacts with Ryzen 5 3400G APU

Tags: graphics, amd-ryzen

I built a new computer and am now getting weird graphics glitches when browsing the web or streaming video in a browser.

https://i.imgur.com/hJJm5aY.png

https://i.imgur.com/X74isqn.png

https://i.imgur.com/2ka12zm.mp4 (this one isn't mine, but similar to what is happening to me)

My setup:

[Ryzen 5 3400G processor with integrated graphics](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-ryzen-5-3400g)

[Gigabyte B450M DS3H motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450M-DS3H-rev-10/sp#sp) (BIOS is updated with latest firmware), 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 3200

Connected to [Samsung Q70R QLED Smart 4K TV](https://www.samsung.com/us/televisions-home-theater/tvs/qled-4k-tvs/55--class-q70-qled-smart-4k-uhd-tv--2019--qn55q70rafxza/) (old computer and HDMI cable worked fine with this TV)

I have tried many of the fixes that I found searching online, but none of them seem to completely fix the problem. I have tried fresh installs of the latest Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 versions. I have tried a couple methods of updating or changing the kernel versions. Changing resolutions, refresh rates, or scaling does not fix the issue.

Current configuration after fresh 20.04 install:

lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

uname -a

```
Linux media-server 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci | grep VGA

```
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c8)
```

sudo lshw -c video

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Picasso
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: c8
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:101 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcb00000-fcb7ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problems can be observed with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS / Ryzen 3 3200G / Gigabyte B450M S2H /
16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 3200.

#### Workaround 1:

Disable IOMMU in BIOS.

#### Workaround 2:

Add `iommu=pt` to command line in `/etc/default/grub` following the steps below.

1. Run

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Make the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line look like this

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash iommu=pt"
   ```
3. Update grub by

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot with

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: Disabling IOMMU in the BIOS completely fixed the issue on my setup (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS / Ryzen 5 3400G / Gigabyte B450M DS3H / 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 3200). Thank you so much for the response!

Comment: What does disabling this do?

Comment: my setup too was fixed by adding iommu=pt. my configuration is ubuntu 20, ryzen 3200g,  Gigabyte GA-AB350M-DS3H, thanks a lot

Comment: I also had to add iommu=pt on my ryzen 3400g.  I would love to see a detailed technical explanation of why this fixes the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a third workaround ?

The prompt is displayed ok (same picture  on both screen)
Then my display is sliced horizontally
Each slice is shifted

I disabled IOMMU in the bios, changed the grub conf
Activated dual screen in bios too.

HDMI monitor on HDMI (full hd)
VGA monitor on HDMI>VGA on a DP>HDMI passive adapter  (1650x ???)
This is not a hardware issue or bios setting issue as I have dual screen working

Fresh ubuntu 20.04 install with kernel 5.4

Found a 3rd workaround with this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWg8q_f7nI4

Comment: Have you tested this workaround on an APU, please? The video seems to be about AMD dedicated GPUs, which work very differently.

Comment: My hw is a B550 motherboard with a ryzen5 3400G (an APU)
Since then, plenty of updates have reached my install like new linux firmware packages.
I also gave 2G Ram for the graphics (at bios level).

It was weird and angrying as dual screen worked on windows.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that you are using an APU. I have just bought a 3400G so it is very helpful to know that the 3rd workaround can be used.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.10

While support for these devices has been in the kernel for a while, I've found I've had missing firmware when I see an update-initramfs. I also saw some AMDGPU-specific commits to upstream linux-firmware a little while ago, and tried the latest available deb package for Hirsute - it fixed all of my weird issues with the system, including requiring software IOMMU

YMMV, but try the 1.191 deb package under https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware

Edit: step by step instructions as requested!

1. Navigate to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware
2. Expand the 1.191 arrow, under The Hirsute Hippo branch
3. Download linux-firmware_1.191_all.deb
4. Install the new firmware
   `sudo apt install /path/to/linux-firmware_1.191_all.deb`
5. Reboot

Edit2: For reference, I have two AMD systems this really helped with. One is a Dell Inspiron 5585 w/ AMD Ryzen 3500U, the other is one I built with an AMD Ryzen 3400G.

Comment: Could you please clarify what system you tested this on? It would be helpful to know a motherboard + APU combination that definitely works. And to have confirmation that you are using the integrated graphics, not a dedicated GPU.

Comment: Sure thing, info added!

Comment: Thank you. I have just bought a 3400G to use with Ubuntu. Would you mind sharing what what motherboard you have found works? I have bought a B450 Mortar Max, but it's not too late for me to return it.

Comment: Matthew, I'm personally using an ASUS Prime A320I-K motherboard, with the AMD A320 chipset. That said, your B450 should be fine, and the process I've described for adding the newer AMD firmware should work for you

Comment: I tried this workaround. Unfortunately it did not fix my graphics problem. However, my problem is slightly different: the graphics freeze and the system log reports `*ERROR* Waiting for fences timed out!`, as per [this bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/934).