# Ubuntu 20.04 Visual Glitch

Tags: drivers, graphics

So I decided to give another linux distro a try as the visual bug I get happens on alot of distros, I have tried Solus, Mint, Arch and Pop all of them have the same issue, ubuntu has been the best one for me so far but there still a little visual glitch that happens. I have install the proper amd drivers from their site aswell as made a .conf.d file, I also have tried using ubuntu wayland. I am using a Ryzen 3 3200g if that is any use?

One more thing to note, this doesn't happen when using windows and I use a virtual box. But I really want ubuntu to be my daily driver but I just cannot get this fixed. I have included a screenshot below of what happens.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryPJt.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphics glitches and artifacts with Ryzen 5 3400G APU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239149/graphics-glitches-and-artifacts-with-ryzen-5-3400g-apu)